# SpriteKit - Stop object movement when collide with wall

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit, ios7.1

I'm new to SpriteKit, I make simple test game and I have issue with colliding objects.

Player must collide with wall. Currently player moves trough the wall. Here is sample of the code :

Set up of Player :

```
SKSpriteNode *player = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"player"];

player.name = playerCategoryName;

player.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:player.frame.size];
player.physicsBody.restitution = 0.1f;
player.physicsBody.friction = 0.0f;
player.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;

player.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypePlayer;
player.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypeNet ;
player.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = CollisionTypeWall;
```

Set up of net :

```
SKSpriteNode *wall = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[UIColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(20, 350)];

    wall.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), self.wall.frame.size.height * 0.6);
    wall.physicsBody = [SKPhysicsBody bodyWithRectangleOfSize:size];
    wall.physicsBody.dynamic = NO;
    wall.physicsBody.categoryBitMask = CollisionTypeWall;
    wall.physicsBody.contactTestBitMask = 0;
    wall.physicsBody.collisionBitMask = CollisionTypePlayer;

    [self addChild:wall];
```

Any help will be appreciated !

Comment: [self addChild:wall]; , is self is a your scene?, make sure you are adding wall and player to physics world

Comment: How can both objects collide with dynamic set to NO? Also, 2 objects with a dynamic = NO will not register collision.

Comment: Thanks! You are right I didn't see that dynamic is set to NO.